# Using bashrc to define an alias in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

I need to define an alias for ls -al named parisan.

I tried:

```
nano .bashrc
```

i defined :

```
alias parisan = ls -al
```

but when i call it using alias parian in terminal i get this error:

> the alias parisan not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define an alias you have to use the syntax:

```
alias parisan='ls -al'
              ^^      ^
              |-quotes-
              | 
              |___ no spaces around =
```

And then source the file so that you can start using `parisan` as an alias:

```
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
alias parisan='ls -al'
```